# How to construct an n-ary tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, constructor, tree, nodes

I am trying to solve some algorithm questions, and am unfamiliar with how to construct an n-ary tree in JavaScript.  I am given a definition of class Node as below:

```
class Node {
    constructor(val, children) {
        this.val = val;
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

I want to write an `add` method to this class; however, I am confused on how to do it.  I know `this.children` should be an array.  The first value somehow should be identified as the root, and then subsequent adds should be children.  Or at least that's my logic, but not sure how to implement.  Let's say I want to construct the n-ary tree below.  How would I do it?

```
             1
          /  |  \
         /   |   \
        3    2    4
      /   \
     5     6
```

`Input: root = [1, null, 3, 2, 4, null, 5, 6].`

This input is what I get for the tree above according to a problem I am trying to solve.

`Nary-Tree input serialization is represented in their level order traversal, each group of children is separated by the null value.`

How can I modify the class definition to construct the above tree, so that eventually I can try traverse through them to solve for it's maximum depth?

Comment: The input makes no sense to me.

Comment: Found this in  the problem set `Nary-Tree input serialization is represented in their level order traversal, each group of children is separated by the null value`

Comment: based on your visual tree, maybe the input should be `[1, [3, 5, 6], 2, 4]`?

Comment: the input is given based on a leetcode problem #559. Maximum Depth of N-ary Tree

Comment: I am just trying to figure out how to convert the tree above into code

Comment: I think you misunderstand how leetcode works. The serialised representation is taken care of by leetcode itself: it will unserialise the input, create the `Node` instances and pass the root node to the actual function you need to write. You only need to return the depth of the tree. Forget about that serialised array format.

Comment: I agree with @trincot . But, if you still want to unserialize, you probably want to have a structure for keeping track of the last "level" of children (let's call them new parents). You loop on it adding children (updating also at the time another list of current children level which will become the last level afterward), and any time you find a null, you move to the next new parent. When no more "new parent" available, switch to current children as new last level of children.

Comment: Yes I am aware leetcode doesn't require me to do this.  I just wanted to be able to test my code in my own editor.  I agree with your logic lctus, but wasn't able to come up with the code myself.